# Replace files in a folder with files in other folder, using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have two folders.

1. Folder1 contains many files.
2. Folder2 is a service pack for a set of files in folder1.

I want to replace the specific files in Folder1 with the files in Folder2 via PowerShell.

Is `-Replace` the right place to start? How should I approach this?

**Update**

```
Get-ChildItem $hotfix | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $original -force}
```

Comment: look at `copy-item` with a `-force` to overwrite, come back with some examples that you have tried and have trouble with. `-Replace` is more of string replacement related not file/directory related.

Comment: i tried with the following code, and it worked perfectly -Get-ChildItem $hotfix | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $original -force}

Comment: nice work, good job.

Comment: @ruchasn Post an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I am posting the answer late. but here it is !!

so,
1. Folder1 is named $original
2. Folder2 is named $hotfix

```
Get-ChildItem $hotfix | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $original -force}
```

This replces all the common files of $original and $hotfix with the files in $hotfix !

Comment: With subfolder => `Get-ChildItem $hotfix | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $original -Recurse -force}`